# Cordova SQLite Plugin Compatibility

Tags: ios, sqlite, cordova, sqlite.swift, watchos-4

I'm looking to build an iOS hybrid application that also utilizes an Apple Watch application. The watchOS app collects Altimeter data to be stored, and that's it. I was thinking of using this plugin since the watchOS portion is written in Swift. I haven't yet begun the iPhone app, it's just blank right now, but was thinking of making it a hybrid application using Cordova. I've been searching for the best way to share data between the applications, and I think SQLite may be the easiest.

[This cordova plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-sqlite-2) can be used to manipulate data in an SQLite database using JS. That could be used in the iPhone app. I guess my quesiton is - is this possible? If I create a database in swift using this library, will the Cordova plugin be able to access it? Does anyone have any better ideas for sharing data from a native watchkit app to a hybrid iPhone app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will not work. If you create a SQLite database in the watch application running *on the watch* which is a physically different device than the iPhone running your cordova app, how should the application running on the iPhone access the database?

The way to go to use a watch-kit application in combination with a cordova app is [cordova-plugin-apple-watch](https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-apple-watch). The plugin offers three different possibilities to communicate between the watch app and the iphone app:

- [Message passing](https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-apple-watch#message-passing)
- [Local notifications](https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-apple-watch#notifications) and
- [User defaults](https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-apple-watch#user-defaults)

If the data should be accessible by both apps and it should be persistent (like a database) the way to go is probably user defaults. But if you just want to send data from your watch-app to your cordova-app (which will not be needed on the watch anymore) then message passing does also work (the cordova-app can then store the data wherever you want).